# How can I pass value from jQuery to jsf h:inputText and Backing Bean

Tags: javascript, jsf, jquery

I try to pass value from jquery to jsf and Backing Bean. And in the process, I do not want to use f:ajax from jsf-Tag.

javaScript or jQuery

```
<script>
   var myvalue = null;
   $('.classname').live('click',function(){
      myvalue = "thisvalue"+xyz;  
      // update myvalue in jsf inputtext and in bean
   });
</script>
```

JSF - Content

```
<h:form id="myid" prependId="false">

  <h:inputText id="fragment" value="#{myBean.changevalue}">
  <!-- please do not use here f:ajax or p:ajax so on. -->

</h:form>
```

Bean Content

```
private String changevalue;

public String getChangevalue() {
  return changevalue;
}

public void setChangevalue(String changevalue) {
  this.changevalue = changevalue;
}
```

Comment: are you want to update <h:inputText id="fragment"/> value or add new paramter and send to your bean

Answer (score 2):

just you have to set val to browser textbox id  in jquery

for example

```
 <script>
   var myvalue = null;
   $('.classname').live('click',function(){
      myvalue = "thisvalue"+xyz;  

     $("#myid\\:fragment").val(myvalue);

   });
</script>
```

**it will automatically bind value to your bean**

hope it's help for you .

Comment: @murat : Yes, Ravi is right, plz try this code. it might help you.