# Passing Value from Jquery function to JSF ManagedBean

Tags: jquery, jsf

I have implemented the drag and drop with datagrid of primefaces. It works well.
Then i wanted to get the position of the draggable object:
i included that in my handleDrop jquery function, this way:

```
function handleDrop(event, ui) {
        var droppedQuery = ui.draggable;
        var p = ui.offset;
        var myvalue = "thisvalue" + p.left;

        $("#form1\\:position").val(myvalue);      }

<p:inputText id="position" value="#{dragQueryMB.changevalue}"   />
```

The problem is that the text is shown and updated everytime i drag the obrject, but the value of changevalue in the dragQueryMB ManagedBean is alawys is null.

Thank you, i am here for further explanation

Comment: Please post a SSCCE, otherwise no one would know the cause of the problem, for example how do you submit your form ? update your question with SSCCE

Comment: I think posting all the problem around would bore the audience, my question is how to pass parameter from a jquery function (here the handleDrop) to a backing bean. after research, i have found that it can be done by putting a hidden or input Text that made the link between the jquery function and the backing as suggested here for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15783987/how-can-i-pass-value-from-jquery-to-jsf-hinputtext-and-backing-bean. my problem was that after doing that the backing bean value still null.

Comment: However, you are right to ask for post method because that was the problem and i post the solution just below

Answer (score 0):

I have found what was the problem.
Actually, the handleDrop was called on drop event. 
The value of myvalue was passed to the inputText, changes everyTime i call handleDrop function, but all these was client side.
So I have had to make the event calling the handleDrop function process a request so that the backing bean responds and its attributes are up to date. So i added here process=":form1" to the ajax behavior associated to the droppable element
`<p:droppable for="report" tolerance="touch" activeStyleClass="ui-state-highlight"
                         datasource="availablequeries" onDrop="handleDrop" dropListener="#{dragQueryMB.dropQuery()}" >
          <p:ajax listener="#{dragQueryMB.dropQuery}" update="dropArea" process=":form1"/>
        </p:droppable>` 
I hope i was clear enough